# Grunt Babel Taking 6 Seconds Per File

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, babeljs

I'm trying to use Babel in my grunt build process to transpile my `.js` project files from ES6 to ES5. I have a `watch` task watching my `.js` directory for changes and when changes are detected, I run the `babel` task.

For some reason though, changing just one `.js` file takes anywhere between 6-10 seconds to complete. I have a feeling it's transpiling the entire project, but I'm not sure. My `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    babel: {
      files: ["<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js"],
      tasks: ["babel"]
    },
    livereload: {
      options: {
        livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
      },
      files: [
        "{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/**/*.js",
      ]
    }
  },
  babel: {
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      presets: ['es2015']
    },
    dist: {
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/',
          src: ['**/*.js'],
          dest: '.tmp/scripts/'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
grunt.registerTask("serve", function(target) {
  return grunt.task.run(["watch"]);
});
```

When I run `grunt serve` and change a file it logs the execution time:

> Running "babel:dist" (babel) task
>
> Done, without errors.
>
> Execution Time (2015-12-01 11:57:54 UTC)
>   babel:dist  6.7s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%
>   Total 6.7s

But when I use `babel-cli` in my terminal, it transpiles in milliseconds, almost instantaneously even:

```
babel --presets es2015 script.js --out-file transpiled.js
```

Surely this is way too long. Am I doing something wrong here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I switched from using the es2015 preset to selecting plugins manually and that cut the transpilation time to about 1 second. HTH.

Comment: @KevinGorski How are you selecting plugins manually?

Comment: This comment box is terrible. Use the plugins array instead of the presets array. http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ and http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/ something like: `plugins: ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions", "transform-es2015-for-of"]`

Comment: @KevinGorski It transpiles quicker, but doesn't output ES5. Just ES6.

Comment: Uh then it's not really transpiling, maybe just reformatting. There's a flag for code generation, but it's on by default. You could turn on verbose mode for grunt or move the options to .bablerc and try from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

During development you can decide to run the JS version of the Babel-core directly in the browser,  which runs quite fast.

Then for deployment you can make a specific Grunt build task that removes the Babel-Core from the HTML and instead transpiles the files with the Grunt Babel plugin.

Your Gruntfile will have something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['processhtml', 'babel']);
grunt.registerTask('default', [''watch']);
```

For the removal of the Babel-core JS you can use plugins like like grunt-processhtml: http://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml . The HTML will look like this:

```
<!-- build:remove -->   
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->
```

The JS Babel-core can found here: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-core . You can download it and add it to your project or just run it from the CDN directly.