# why is babel transpilation very slow?

Tags: performance, babeljs

I've started coding with es6 and angular and using babel for transpilation of my es6 code. I'm seeing a lot of delay in transpilation as my code base is increasing. This transpilation is taking more than a minute.
I'm using grunt and configured a task for babel.
Is there anything wrong i'm doing here? please suggest.

```js
babel: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: false,
                presets: ['es2015']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'client/',
                        src: ['table/**/*.js'],
                        dest: 'dist/'
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'client/',
                        src: ['main.js'],
                        dest: 'dist/'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Comment: Can you provide your task?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear explanation for this but I did post a possible solution to prevent the long transpilation times during development: [Grunt Babel Taking 6 Seconds Per File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019931/grunt-babel-taking-6-seconds-per-file#38740530)